# UK Citizen traveling to Schengen on February 1st: what changes?

Tags: brexit

I'm a UK citizen traveling to the Schengen area on February 1st. It is, literally, the day after Brexit. What changes? Should I worry about documentation?

Answer (score 5):

The UK Government is maintaining a web page with detailed information on [what you need to do after Brexit to travel to Europe](https://www.gov.uk/visit-europe-brexit).

Nothing will change immediately, but after 1 January 2021, the following changes are expected:

- Your passport may need at least 6 months validity remaining
- You may need travel insurance as your EHIC card might not be valid
- If driving, you may need an IDP, green card and GB oval sticker
- You'll be able to stay 90 days out of every 180 days in Schengen
- You cannot use your EU pet passport for pet travel
- You can no longer use EU/EEA/Switzerland lanes at the border

The UK maintain a [Prepare for Brexit web site](https://www.gov.uk/prepare-eu-exit) with further information including permanent links to the above travel information. If there are changes in the meantime, they will be reflected at those links.

Comment: **Visit Europe from 1 January 2021**, so that shouldn't make any difference ATM, then?

Comment: The 1 January 2021 page links to [The UK leaves the EU on 31 January 2020](https://www.gov.uk/transition), which says "After 31 January 2020 there will be a transition period until the end of 2020, while the UK and EU negotiate additional arrangements."

Comment: Damn, I've had such a long day I don't even know what year it is anymore.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have that problem every January.

Comment: Also I saw on ITV This Morning that apparently the UK has until 1 July 2020 to ask for yet another extension so if they do that then these changes could be deferred again.